# iOS Permission description limit

Tags: ios, ios-permissions

I want to know if is there any limit to define a message for iOS Permission description on info.plist.

I've searched for it but I didn't found nothing about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specified text limit for [Requesting Permission](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/) and a ***plist*** can be of arbitrary length. Also the description scrolls the text automatically.

But it is suggested to keep it simple and short in [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/).

> Explain why your app needs the information. Provide custom text (known as a purpose string or usage description string) for display in the system's permission request alert, and include an example. **Keep the text short** and specific, use sentence case, and be polite so people don't feel pressured. There’s no need to include your app name—the system already identifies your app.